# Why does the first call to a function take significantly longer than subsequent calls in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to measure the performance of drawing a board made of tiles.

One option is to draw he tiles one by one and another option is to first populate the tiles into an image and then just draw a static image

Drawing an image is WAY faster than drawing the tiles one by one.

However I noticed that the first time I run a function it takes significantly more time than the following calls to that function.

What is the reason for this first call to take much longer?

Here's my code

```
let img;
let NROWS = 55;
let NCOLS = 29;
const TILE_WIDTH_HALF = 32;
const TILE_HEIGHT_HALF = 16;
const HALF_WIDTH = 950;
const HALF_HEIGHT = 450;
let start, end;
let bg;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("tile.png");
}

// Populates the background graphics
function populateBackground() {
  bg = createGraphics(HALF_WIDTH*2, HALF_HEIGHT*2);
  for (let row=0; row<NROWS; row++) {
    for (let col=0; col<NCOLS; col++) {
      x = col*TILE_WIDTH_HALF*2 + (TILE_WIDTH_HALF * (row%2)+1)
      y = row*TILE_HEIGHT_HALF;
      bg.image(img, x, y);
    }
  }
}

// draws tile by tile into the canvas
function drawTileByTile() {
  background(100);  
  start = millis();
  for (let row=0; row<NROWS; row++) {
    for (let col=0; col<NCOLS; col++) {
      x = col*TILE_WIDTH_HALF*2 + (TILE_WIDTH_HALF * (row%2)+1) - HALF_WIDTH;
      y = row*TILE_HEIGHT_HALF - HALF_HEIGHT;
      image(img, x, y);
    }
  }
  end = millis();
  return (end-start);  
}

// draws the prepopulated graphics as a single image
function drawAsImage() {
  background(100);
  start = millis();
  image(bg,-HALF_WIDTH,-HALF_HEIGHT);
  end = millis();
  return (end-start);  
}

function setup() 
{
  createCanvas(HALF_WIDTH*2, HALF_HEIGHT*2, WEBGL);
  populateBackground();

  // Draw tile by tile 10 times
  let elapsed_ms = [];
  for (let n=0; n<10; n++) {
    elapsed_ms.push(drawTileByTile().toFixed(3));
  }
  console.log(elapsed_ms);
  
  // Draw as image 10 times
  elapsed_ms = [];
  for (let n=0; n<10; n++) {
    elapsed_ms.push(drawAsImage().toFixed(3));
  }
  console.log(elapsed_ms);

  noLoop();
}

function draw()
{
  
}
```

And the timings. As you can see, drawing tile by tile takes around 35ms and drawing as an image takes 0.1ms (using WEBGL and a GPU in both cases)

However I'm more interested in the first call taking between 4 to 10 times more than the next calls.

```
sketch.js:61 (10) ['114.400', '35.400', '37.000', '31.800', '54.200', '51.900', '33.000', '34.400', '30.200', '31.200']
sketch.js:68 (10) ['1.000', '0.100', '0.100', '0.000', '0.100', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
```

Here's a link to P5 editor, so you can run the code yourselves

https://editor.p5js.org/SembeiNorimaki/sketches/E13qBvAyn

Comment: guess is image is cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `image()` function in `p5.js` with the `WEBGL` renderer, the image that you specify is used as a texture for a uniform that is passed to a `GLSL` shader program that draws pixels of that texture to the triangles that are actual drawn based on the coordinates you specify in your call tor `image()`.

The `p5.Texture` instance [is indeed cached](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/4686ebd02cd290c714d98a9d20dd2d84bf128e14/src/webgl/p5.RendererGL.js#L1492) for the specified image by reference. Additionally `p5.Texture` contains [its own caching logic](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/4686ebd02cd290c714d98a9d20dd2d84bf128e14/src/webgl/p5.Texture.js#L200) to avoid re-copying texture data if the `p5.Image` has not been modified.

In essence, in order to use a `p5.Image` instance as a WEBGL texture, you have to allocate *graphics* memory and copy the image data from the source to the allocated buffer. As it turns out that process is much more costly than just drawing a few triangles that render pixels from that buffer.